# Terraform: ignore changes to a certain environment variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have an AWS Lambda function I created using terraform. Code-changes are auto-deployed from our CI-server and the commit-sha is passed as an environment variable (`GIT_COMMIT_HASH`) - *so this changes the Lambda function outside of the Terraform-scope (because people were asking...)*.

This works good so far. But now I wanted to update the function's node-version and terraform tries to reset the env var to the initial value of `"unknown"`.

I tried to use the `ignore_changes` block but couldn't get terraform to ignore the changes made elsewhere ...

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test" {
  filename      = data.archive_file.helloworld.output_path
  function_name = "TestName_${var.environment}"
  role          = aws_iam_role.test.arn
  handler       = "src/index.handler"

  runtime = "nodejs14.x"
  timeout = 1
  memory_size = 128

  environment {
    variables = {
      GIT_COMMIT_HASH = "unknown"
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      environment.0.variables["GIT_COMMIT_HASH"],
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible? How do I have to reference the variable?

** edit **

Plan output looks like this:

```
# aws_lambda_function.test will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "test" {
        # ... removed some lines

        source_code_size               = 48012865
        tags                           = {}
        timeout                        = 1
        version                        = "12"

      ~ environment {
          ~ variables = {
              ~ "GIT_COMMIT_HASH" = "b7a77d0" -> "unknown"
            }
        }

        tracing_config {
            mode = "PassThrough"
        }
    }
```

Comment: "couldn't get terraform to ignore the changes made elsewhere " - what do you mean by that? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin the CI-server updated the lambda's env var to the current git sha but my terraform script does not know that, so it wants to change it back to `"unknown"`. I want the tf script to ignore this change and to only update the node-version from 12->14

Comment: What does the plan output look like?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR added the output

Comment: Ignoring `environment.0.variables` (without the variable name at the end) works for all environment variables but I only want to ignore `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` ... no luck so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to **replicate** the issue and in my tests it works exactly as expected. I can only suspect that you are using an old version of TF, where this issue occurs. There has been numerous GitHub Issues reported regarding the limitations of `ignore_changes`. For example, [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17608), [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22504) or [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13192).

I performed tests using `Terraform v0.15.3` with `aws v3.31.0`, and I can confirm that `ignore_changes` works as it should. Since this is a TF internal problem, the only way to rectify the problem, to the best of my knowledge, would be to **upgrade** your TF.

Comment: by "as expected" you mean it ignores the changes to the `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` var? will have to check which version I'm using...

Comment: @PhilippKyeck Yes. `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` was ignored in my tests.

Comment: Yes, that is working!! Thank you very much. Because I was testing different syntax I still had `environment.0.variables.GIT_COMMIT_HASH` and not `environment.0.variables["GIT_COMMIT_HASH"]` and the first one isn't working whereas the second one works as it should!

Comment: Hey @Marcin I want to use `ignore_changes` for lambda to ignore UUID change made to event_source_mapping externally, is this possible? I couldn't find proper documentation to it.